# complex elasticsearch query over rest

Tags: rest, elasticsearch, lucene

using Rest from classic asp I am able to retrieve data from an index when I perform a simple search such as:

```
Set xml = Server.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")

xml.Open "GET", "http://elastic:changeme@10.128.128.109:9200/myindex/_search?q='fred blogs',_source='path.real'", False
```

I now want to retrive data from a much more complex query that if I was using Kibana would look something like this:

```
GET newsindex/_search
{
"query": {
"function_score": {
  "query": { "bool" : {"should": [ 
   { "term": { "headline": "brown" } },
   { "term": {  "bodytext": "brown" } },
   { "term": { "headline": "fox" } },
   { "term": { "bodytext": "fox" } }
]}},
  "functions": [
    {
      "filter": {"match" : { "headline": "brown fox" }},
      "weight": 2
    },
    {
      "filter": {"match" : { "bodytext": "brown fox" }},
      "weight": 1
    },
    {
      "filter": {"match" : { "bodytext": "fox" }},
      "weight": 3
    },
    {
      "filter": {"match" : { "bodytext": "brown" }},
      "weight": 3
    },
    {
      "filter": {"match" : { "headline": "brown" }},
      "weight": 4
    },
    {
      "filter": {"match" : { "headline": "fox" }},
      "weight": 4
    }
    ],
  "score_mode": "sum"
}
},"sort": [
{
  "_score": {
    "order": "asc"
  }
}
], 
"_source":[ "headline", "bodytext" ]
}
```

How can I pass this query using Rest? I'll be building queries like this on the fly to pass via rest. But I need to get the construct right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using [curl](https://curl.haxx.se/) command, you can do something like this:

```
curl -XGET "http://elastic:changeme@10.128.128.109:9200/myindex/_search" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "should": [
            {
              "term": {
                "headline": "brown"
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "bodytext": "brown"
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "headline": "fox"
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "bodytext": "fox"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "functions": [
        {
          "filter": {
            "match": {
              "headline": "brown fox"
            }
          },
          "weight": 2
        },
        {
          "filter": {
            "match": {
              "bodytext": "brown fox"
            }
          },
          "weight": 1
        },
        {
          "filter": {
            "match": {
              "bodytext": "fox"
            }
          },
          "weight": 3
        },
        {
          "filter": {
            "match": {
              "bodytext": "brown"
            }
          },
          "weight": 3
        },
        {
          "filter": {
            "match": {
              "headline": "brown"
            }
          },
          "weight": 4
        },
        {
          "filter": {
            "match": {
              "headline": "fox"
            }
          },
          "weight": 4
        }
      ],
      "score_mode": "sum"
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "_score": {
        "order": "asc"
      }
    }
  ],
  "_source": [
    "headline",
    "bodytext"
  ]
}'
```

You can send your query in data by using curl. I'm sure the same can also be achieved by your Rest client. Just check how to send data using your Rest client.

This [post](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/290591/how-to-submit-form-data-by-using-xmlhttp-or-serverxmlhttp-object) might help. Replace the `DataToSend` variable in the example with your query and see if this works.

Comment: No this isn't any good. I specifically need to use xmlhttp object as per my post. Following the the link. if I set the URI up to localhost:9200 and then place the rest in the data object it fails miserably. I expect elasticsearch doesn't know what to do with it in this form.

Comment: I had another look at the link you sent. I continued to 'play' with this. I needed to introduce basic authentication into the header and send my query as a 'body' and finally got it to work. I'll accept this as the answer since you got me on my way.